# Existential introduction - required or not?

Tags: first-order-logic, quantifiers, proof-theory

Consider a theory $T$ in first order logic, and a formula $C$. If there exist a proof of $C$, and that all formulas in $T$ and $C$, none of them contains $\exists$.

The question is: does there always exist a proof of $C$ that do not invoke $\exists$ introduction?

My intuition say no. I constructed some formulas as follow:

$\neg\forall xP(x)$

$\forall x(\neg P(x)\rightarrow\neg Q(x))$

as the theory. And the conclusion is $\neg\forall Q(x)$.

It seems intuitive that you can't avoid getting $\exists x\neg P(x)$ somewhere in the proof. But I can't quite prove that all proof will have something like that sentence, or otherwise use $\exists$ introduction somewhere.

Hope someone can help with this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand the statement of your problem; so I try to interpret it as :

> Consider a theory $T$ in first order logic, and a formula $C$ such that all formulae in $T$ nor $C$ contain $\exists$. Does always exist a proof of $C$ from $T$ that do not invoke $∃$-introduction?

I do not know if you are considering specifically *natural deduction*, but - in general - we can have a *proof system* for *first-order* logic (see Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122384520) (2nd - 2001)) which use only $\forall$ as primitive (obviously : $\exists$ is defined as an abbrevation for $\lnot \forall \lnot$).

A system like Enderton's is *sound* and *complete* for *validity*.

Thus if we have : $\Gamma \vdash \alpha$, where no formula in $\Gamma$ nor $\alpha$ contain $\exists$, we have that the proof does not need logical axioms or inference rules with $\exists$, simply because there are none in the system.

---

Regarding your example, we can prove it as follows, using axiom :

> $\forall x \alpha \rightarrow \alpha(x/t)$, where $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $\alpha$ [see Enderton, page 112]

and some tautological equivalences.

*Proof*

*(1)* $\forall x (\lnot P(x) \rightarrow \lnot Q(x))$ --- assumed

*(2)* $\lnot \forall x P(x)$ --- assumed

*(3)* $\lnot P(x) \rightarrow \lnot Q(x)$ --- from (1) and axiom, by *mp*

*(4)* $Q(x) \rightarrow P(x)$ --- from (3) by *contraposition*

*(5)* $\forall x Q(x)$ --- "temporary" assumption

*(6)* $Q(x)$ --- from (5) and axiom, by *mp*

*(7)* $P(x)$ --- from (4) and (6) by *mp*

*(8)* $\forall x P(x)$ --- from (7) by **Generalization Th** [see Enderton, page 117 : $x$ is not *free* in the assumptions].

But (2) and (8) are contradictory; thus by *Reductio Ad Absurdum* [see Enderton, page 119] :

> > *(9)* $\lnot \forall x Q(x)$ --- "discharging" assumption (5).

Comment: I am asking about the standard first order logic, with the standard rule of inference. (perhaps there are more than one standard, but I only know one)

Comment: Oh, so it still can be done without $\exists$ introduction. Guess I'm back to square 1. Is there anyway to prove or this prove the question then?

Comment: @Gina - having shown you that we can prove it in a system where rgere is **no** $\exists$-introduction rule, it seems to me that it is enough to conclude that it always exists a proof without it ...

Comment: Even though this answer have not answered my question fully, I accept it on account that it provided me with some interesting information.

Comment: @Gina - Thanks ... but in order to "refute" my incomplete (I agree with you) argument, it is enough to find a valid formula of f-o logic that is impossible to prove without $\exists$-intro ...

Comment: @Gina - a last question: what is for you "the standard first order logic, with the standard rule of inference" ? Is it *Natural Deduction* ? If so, clearly you have the $\exists$ quantifier and the two $\exists$-intro and -elim rules. But still, my proof above holds, because it needs only $\forall$-elim and -intro, $\rightarrow$-elim and the final step with *RAA*. I still suppose that if $T$ does not contain $\exists$, the only way to have it along the proof is by use of $\exists$-intro; but in this way, $\exists$ will be in the conclusion $C$, **unless** we "remove" it by an $\exists$-elim.

Comment: It is indeed natural deduction. I only know the version I learnt, which is taught in class using the Fitch program from Stanford. Basically, for each of $\forall,\exists,\neg,\vee,\wedge,\rightarrow,\leftrightarrow,\perp$ there is a pair of intro/elim. Yes, clearly if we have the symbol somewhere in $T$ or $C$ there is no avoiding $\exists$-intro/elim, but I wish to know if it is still unavoidable even when not in that situation. It is possible that some system without $\exists$ can prove things because they have inference rules that "jump over" those $\exists$-intro/elim.